# Postman refuses to work when Authorization header is present

Tags: rest, postman

Whenever I try to make a request that has an `Authorization` header, I immediately get a no response header. This is independent of whether the actual API is under auth. Meanwhile, same requests work fine if I convert the request to curl code from Postman and run that in terminal.

I tried everything that Postman suggests: SSL verification is off, I'm not using any proxy, and my request timeout is pretty high.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check in the Postman console if the header is actually being sent with the request.

Comment: (There's no need to put answers in the question - adding them below, as you have done, is fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working fine now, no longer an issue in latest version of Postman.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem and made it work by setting username and password in the Authorization tab of Postman instead of setting Authorization header in the Headers tab.

[image]

Comment: Not an option for me, the authorization is not username/password based.